# A problem about using characteristic equation to solve recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm working on a recursive sequence. However, I found that the roots of the characteristic equation are complex numbers. Does it mean there isn't a general term formula for this sequence, thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, how can I know that whether there exists a general term formula for a sequence? Thanks.

Comment: The general form can be obtained in the same way when the roots are real or complex.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HHY You can try putting it into Wolfram Alpha

Comment: I've tried. However, I failed to find the answer.

Comment: Why not to post the recursive sequence in the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution goes through as normal, just using exponentials of complex quantities. I.e., if you've got:

$\begin{align*}
  \exp(a + b n + (c + d n) \mathrm{i})
    &= \exp(a + b n) \cdot (\cos (c + d n) + \mathrm{i} \sin(c + d n))
\end{align*}$

If the original coefficients are all real, the zeros will show up in complex conjugate pairs, and the sinus terms end up cancelling. Thus you end up with solutions of the form $\alpha \beta^n$ times a periodic term.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!